# Probability of $N \ge n$ points for an inhomogeneous poisson point process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, point-processes

I am trying to figure out the probability of at least n points for an inhomogeneous poisson point process defined on the real line.

$$
P\{N(a,\infty) \ge n \} = ?
$$

I'm also not entirely sure if the following is valid (ie. integrating up to infinity):

$$
P\{N(a,\infty) = n \} = \frac{[\Lambda(a,\infty)]^n}{n!}e^{-\Lambda(a,\infty)}
$$

where $\lambda(t)$  is some locally integrable positive function  (for t>0)

$$
\Lambda(a,\infty) = \int_{a}^{\infty}\lambda(t)dt
$$